# Angular ErrorInterceptor is firing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interceptor that receives a 401 (unauthorized).

Everything looks good, however while i do a single request, the interceptor gets fired twice.Very strange.

```
App.factory('HttpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', '$location','ModalService', function ($q, $injector, $location, ModalService) {
    return {        
        responseError: function (response) {

            if (response.status === 401) {

                console.log("401");

            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
}]);

App.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpResponseInterceptor');
}]);
```

I get in the chrome debugging console " 2 401", meaning it got fired twice

Here is the code that fires the network call.Its only fired once, i checked it via fiddle.

The controller:

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.Open = function () {
        $http.get('/Home/GetSum').
               then(function (response) {
                   alert(response);
               });
    }

}])
```

and the view:

```
<button ng-controller="HomeCtrl" ng-click="Open()">OPEN</button>
```

Note that i am using Ui router.

Comment: It is possible the request got sent twice and got the same result both times. Can we see the code making the request? Or try adding some logging statements into there and see if that only runs once

Comment: i have a console open (fiddle) and its called only once.I will post the code, its a simple button click that posts to an endpoint of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove the $q.reject(response).

If the response return 401 it is automatically rejected

Comment: Thank you it worked.Could you please explain in more detail how errors are handled exactly.The angular documentation is horrific.

Comment: Everytime a response return an error, (4xx, 5xx) it is automaticcaly rejected and you can catch the error using the .catch(function())

EX:
$http.get('/Home/GetSum').
               then(function (response) {
                   alert(response);
               }).catch(function(error){console.log(error)});